# Is Java GMail API thread-safe?

Tags: thread-safety, gmail-api, google-api-java-client

In particular, can multiple threads use the same [`GMail`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/gmail/Gmail.html) service instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. [Gmail](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/gmail/Gmail.html) implementation is not thread-safe.

> Therefore, if you are running as a multi-threaded application, each
>   thread that you are making requests from must have its own instance of
>   `httplib2.Http()`.

Resource Link: [gmail api service](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/index.html?com/google/api/services/gmail/Gmail.Builder.html)